# iOS : How to increase navigation bar size (or merge with another view so I can fill this space with an image)?

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

Here is what I want to do. I have an image like this (this is a just an ugly test image btw), with a size of 320x200.

[image]

I basically want to use the top part of this image to fill my app's navigation bars, so it only uses the first 44px of the image like this:

[image]

I tried this in my `ViewController` :

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar
    .setBackgroundImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "gradient")
    .resizableImage(withCapInsets: .zero, resizingMode: .stretch), for: .default)
```

But it stretches the image and I don't know how to use only the top part of the image without stretching it...

Also, I want in some cases this view to have a bigger height than 44px, using the whole image. In order to get this:

[image]

How can I do it?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: see this https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-give-a-uinavigationbar-a-background-image-setbackgroundimage

Comment: There are few hacks to do it with NavigationBar, but non of them will work "smooth". Navigation bar work perfect with built in size and bar button items but for custom elements, layout and size I'll advice you to hide navigation bar and use custom view instead.

Comment: Ok I get it, thanks for your answer.